# How do I correctly setup caching for my custom block showing content depending on the current node?

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I have this very basic block which just shows the current node's ID.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block\ExampleEmptyBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "example_empty",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Example: empty block")
 * )
 */
class ExampleEmptyBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $build = array();

    if ($node) {
      $config = \Drupal::config('system.site');

      $build = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<p>' . $node->id() . '<p>',
        '#cache' => array(
          'tags' => $this->getCacheTags(),
          'contexts' => $this->getCacheContexts(),
        ),
      );
    }

    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    return Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), ["node:{$node->id()}"]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return Cache::mergeContexts(parent::getCacheContexts(), ['user.node_grants:view']);
  }

}
```

But once cached, the block stays the same, regardless which node I visit. How do I correctly cache the result per node ID?

Comment: Look at `getCacheTags()` from BlockBase, you just need add a tag that represent your node (node:{nid}). Sorry I'm in a hurry now, I can explain better later,

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is full working code with comments.

```
namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

/**
 * Provides a Node cached block that display node's ID.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "node_cached_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Node Cached")
 * )
 */
class NodeCachedBlock extends BlockBase {
  public function build() {
    $build = array();
    //if node is found from routeMatch create a markup with node ID's.
    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
      $build['node_id'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<p>' . $node->id() . '<p>',
      );
    }
    return $build;
  }

  public function getCacheTags() {
    //With this when your node change your block will rebuild
    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
      //if there is node add its cachetag
      return Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), array('node:' . $node->id()));
    } else {
      //Return default tags instead.
      return parent::getCacheTags();
    }
  }

  public function getCacheContexts() {
    //if you depends on \Drupal::routeMatch()
    //you must set context of this block with 'route' context tag.
    //Every new route this block will rebuild
    return Cache::mergeContexts(parent::getCacheContexts(), array('route'));
  }
}
```

I tested it; it works.

Just put the code in a file named NodeCachedBlock.php in your module folder, change its namespace {module_name}, clear the cache and use it.

Comment: so the trick is to remove the `#cache` settings in the build function and just add the public functions?

Comment: That doesn't matter where you set the cache tags and contexts.

Comment: Well, I think that's make more sense, because we are building a block, so block needs to be cached. If you change your block in the future (i.e put some extra render elements), your block will work.

Comment: @4k4 url.path seemed to have worked too. whats the difference?

Comment: @4k4 Tested here, worked nice. Every node have its own route, but can have different paths (path alias).

Comment: @Vagner: Putting cache tags/contexts in the render array is also not a bad idea, because you have it where your data is, which depend on it. And it will always bubble up, so you don't have to worry about the elements that are above. Btw. your code is great, does explain the caching issues very well.

Comment: When visiting a non-node page, I get this error:
`Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::mergeTags() must be of the type array, null given` which is weird since the 2. argument is always `array('node:' . $node->id()`

Comment: @Alex Sry my bad, I forgot `return` in `else` statement in `getCacheTags`  function. fixed now ;)

Comment: How can I do this on each load ? I'm developing a random block and it doesn't change after a simple refresh.

Comment: @Pauloscorps, what you asking for, is deactivate cache for your block, right? This is a valid question for community, maybe its better you make a question to let everyone help you, and the community be able to find solution too. The answer involves uses of `UncacheableDependencyTrait` and `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger()`

Comment: @Vagner I opened a post, although many already exist on this subject. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255883/disabled-caching-on-a-custom-plugin-block

Answer (score 18):

The by far easiest way to do this is to rely on the plugin/block context system.

See my answer for [How do I make a block that pulls the current node content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180907/how-do-i-make-a-block-that-pulls-the-current-node-content)

You just have to put a node context definition in your block annotation like this:

```
*   context_definitions = {
*     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"))
*   }
```

And then use it like this: `$this->getContextValue('node')`

The nice thing about this is that Drupal will then take care of caching for you. Automatically. Because it knows that the default (and as far as core goes only) node context is the current node. And that knows where it is coming from, so the cache context and cache tags are added automatically.

Through `\Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContextAwarePluginBase::getCacheContexts()` and the corresponding `getCacheTags()` methods, BlockBase/your block class extends from that and inherits those methods.

Comment: You replace `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')` with `$this->getContextValue('node')` and you solve the whole caching issue with one line of code? Great!

Comment: thanks so far! could you provide a full code example?

Comment: @Alex: I edited your question. Please check and change the code if you find any error.

Comment: @4k4 I didnt try it out because the other solution works, too

Comment: @Alex – Full code example: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/205155/15055

Comment: the annotation key is now "context_definitions", see https://www.drupal.org/node/3016699

Answer (score 9):

If you derive the class of your block plugin from [`Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21BlockBase.php/class/BlockBase/8.1.x), you will have two methods to set cache tags and contexts.

- `getCacheTags()`
- `getCacheContexts()`

For example, the Book module block implements those methods as follows.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return Cache::mergeContexts(parent::getCacheContexts(), ['route.book_navigation']);
  }
```

The Forum module block uses the following code.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return Cache::mergeContexts(parent::getCacheContexts(), ['user.node_grants:view']);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    return Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), ['node_list']);
  }
```

In your case, I would use the following code.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    return Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), ["node:{$node->id()}"]);
  }
```

You could also use the following method, to make the block uncacheable at all (even if I would avoid it). It could be useful in other cases, maybe.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }
```

Remember to add `use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;` on the top of the file, if you are going to use the `Cache` class.

Comment: thanks, but on /node/2 the block still outputs 1 when I visited node/1 in the first place, after clearing my cache

Comment: If you are editing a module that is enabled, you need to first uninstall it, before editing it. Clearing the cache is not enough.

Comment: okay, but adding the maxAge 0 works, strangely!

Comment: Also, does your block class uses the `BlockBase` class as parent class?

Comment: yes it does use it

Comment: i've updated my question, still no luck even after deinstalling an reenabling the module. only the max age 0 works...

Comment: @kiamlaluno Why do we need to uninstall an enabled module on editing, and why isn't cache clear (cache rebuild like `drush cr`) enough?

Comment: @LarS Because that is the way to let Drupal understand there are new hooks in an existing module. It's the only one I can rely upon.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for your answer. To tell Drupal, that there is a new hook, cache rebuild i.e. by `drush cache-rebuild`/`drush cr` in D8 (cache clear i.e. by `drush cc all` in D7) is just fine, it always worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

When you build a render array, always attach the correct metadata:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

$build['node_id'] = [
  '#markup' => '<p>' . $node->id() . '<p>',
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => $node->getCacheTags(),
    // add a context if the node is dependent on the route match
    'contexts' => ['route'],
  ],
];
```

This is not block specific and the block plugins cache dependency methods getCacheTags(), getCacheContext() and getCacheMaxAge() are not a replacement. They should only be used for additional cache metadata, which can't be delivered through the render array.

See the documentation:

> "It is of the utmost importance that you inform the Render API of the
>   cacheability of a render array."

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

See this example how Drupal expects a render array to provide the necessary cache metadata when optimizing caching through auto-placeholdering and lazy-building [Problem setting user specific cache tags on custom block with user context](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288881/problem-setting-user-specific-cache-tags-on-custom-block-with-user-context)

Comment: I don't think that can set cache of Block object. '#markup' is just a Render Element object and there is no reason to set cache context or tag. The block object that needs to rebuild when cache is invalidate.

Comment: `#markup` can be cached the same as any other render element. In this case it is not the markup, but the block, which is cached and here is the problem. You can't solve it with cache tags, because they only get invalidated, if the node is changed in the database.

Comment: @Vagner You can set the cache of a Block object; The `BlockBase` class has even the necessary methods.

Comment: this doesnt work. the block always outputs the first visited node's id

Comment: OK, then the node does not provide the contexts we need. You can try to set it manually, see the edit in my answer.

Comment: isnt that super weird? you would think the entity does this itself? i am trying...

Comment: thanks for your help, it didnt quite work for me though, but its almost the same solution als Vagners

Comment: For me ```return [
      '#markup' => render($output),
      '#cache'  => [
        'contexts' => ['url']
      ]
    ];``` works super fine for per URL caching.

Comment: Yes, @leymannx, it's as simple as this. This threads seems to overthinking the issue.

Comment: Off-topic: You often see people recommending `['#cache']['max-age'] = 0` to fix minor issues. But isn't this then bubbling up until completely disabling the cache of the current page?

Comment: @leymannx, for blocks which change very often this is actually a good idea, because this meets the default auto-placeholdering conditions and the page can be cached without the block, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/auto-placeholdering

Comment: Ah OK, so thanks to `renderer.config`'s `auto_placeholder_conditions` the auto-placeholdering kicks in and interrupts upbubbling of that very element/subtree that has defined `['#cache']['max-age'] = 0` and the rest of the page/tree can follow its own logic.

Comment: Another off-topic: Would you consider it a good tactic to max age 0 a piece of markup placed via a pseudo field to display user online statuses? https://git.drupalcode.org/project/user_status_online/-/blob/8.x-1.4/user_status_online.module#L54-70 – From what I know now it should be OK, shouldn't it?

Comment: @leymannx , yes, but for placeholdering to work the online status needs to be in a lazy builder callback. For blocks this is default, but not for entities, see `BlockViewBuilder::viewMultiple`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the cache contexts are not declare at the right place in the build function:

```
class ExampleEmptyBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
   $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
   $build = array();

   if ($node) {
    $config = \Drupal::config('system.site');

    $build = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<p>' . $node->id() . '<p>',
    '#cache' => array(
      'tags' => $this->getCacheTags(),
      'contexts' => $this->getCacheContexts(),
    ),
   );
 }
 return $build;
 }
}
```

If you call that block on a non node, the build function return an empty array, so there is no cache context for this block and that behaviour will be cached by drupal: the display of this block will not properly invalidate or be rendered.

Solution is just to initialise the $build with the cache contexts everytime:

```
class ExampleEmptyBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
   $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

    $build = array(
    '#cache' => array(
      'tags' => $this->getCacheTags(),
      'contexts' => $this->getCacheContexts(),
    ),
   );

   if ($node) {
    $config = \Drupal::config('system.site');

    $build['#markup'] = '<p>' . $node->id() . '<p>';
    $build['#type'] = 'markup';
    }
 return $build;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried implementing [`hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter)?

```
function hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I'm late to this conversation, but the below code worked for me:

```
class ExampleBlock extends BlockBase
{

  public function build()
  {
    $lcContent = '';

    $loNode = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

    if (!$loNode)
    {
      return (array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#cache' => array('max-age' => 0),
        '#markup' => $lcContent,
      ));
    }

    $lcContent .= "<div id='example_block' style='overflow: hidden; clear: both;'>\n";
    $lcContent .= $loNode->id();
    $lcContent .= "</div>\n";

    return (array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#cache' => array('max-age' => 0),
      '#markup' => $lcContent,
    ));
  }
}
```