# How can I render multiple values which belong to the same field?

Tags: views, 8

I have a content type with a text field "Person", which assumes up to 3 possible options. I am trying to render a block, where I would display this field with three presons.

```
if(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical'){
  $node = Node::load(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node'));
  if($node->bundle() == "people"){


    // CONTACT
    $render = array();
    if($field = $node->field_contact_person->first()){
      $field = $field->getValue()['value'];
      $render['#markup'] = '<div>'.$field.'</div>';
      $render['#prefix'] = '<div class="block institution"><h3>'.$this->t('Contact person').'</h3>';
      $render['#suffix'] = '</div>';
      $block['#markup'] .= render($render);
    }


  }
}
```

The issue is that it fetches only first value. How can I fetch all values and render them in the block?

Comment: A few remarks: `getParameter('node')` gets the preloaded node directly from the route. Don't render early, return the unrendered build array. You need to add cache data, or better render the node in a view mode or in a Views block, which both would take care of caching.

Comment: ... as far as cache tags are concerned, but you still need to add a context when loading a node from the current route in a block plugin, unless you get the node via a context definition in your block annotation, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199601/47547.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `first()` - that gets the first item.

```
if ($field = $node->field_contact_person) {
  foreach ($field->getValue() as $value) {
    $item_value = $value['value'];
  }
}
```