# Block cache for anonymous users depending on previous behavior

Tags: blocks, caching, 9

I have a content type named "Campaign". Each Campaign has a totally different look and feel in the website.

Once a visitor wants to join a campaign, the user is redirected to the normal Drupal login/register page, but I want that login/register page to have the same look and feel as the campaign the user was visiting. This is already solved because **we know the node ID of the latest visited campaign** and based on that I can add specific campaign CSS and JS files.

But (and here is the question) in the login and register pages we also have a block with an image/link to go back to the campaign. It perfectly works if I disable cache with:

```
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    // If you want to disable caching for this block.
    return 0;
  }
```

But without this option, the first campaign image/link keeps being used even after visiting other campaigns.

What can I use in `getCacheTags` and/or `getCacheContexts` to have different cached versions of my block, based in a totally custom criteria (the ID of the latest campaign node visited by the current user, that we already know!).

Comment: This is a custom block? How is the ID of the last visited campaign stored? In the session? In the URL?

Comment: @cilefen It is a custom block. The ID is stored in the session.

Comment: You need to set a cache context and the one to use is `session`.  There is a good example here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199527/how-do-i-correctly-setup-caching-for-my-custom-block-showing-content-depending-o

Comment: Does your block build a render array? Then don't use these methods. Build a proper render array. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

Comment: @4uk4 Yes, it is a render array, but using `#cache => ['keys' => ['campaign' => $nid]]` isn't working. Shoiuld I add `tags` and/or `context` too?

Comment: Yes, the tag of the node and the context depending on from where you get $nid, see the comment of @cilefen. The key doesn't help. It generates an additional cache entry, which is not necessary, because the block is already cached and the rendered content is cached twice.